# How to prevent unity console from expanding when unity is launched

Tags: unity-game-engine

Anytime I start the Unity application on my MacBook Pro the console ends up expanding, till it has finished loading, preventing me from accessing any other application till I minimise or close it. How can I prevent this from happening, so that the console doesn't expand fullscreen when launching Unity?

Comment: what do you mean by expanding? you mean its full screen?

Comment: yes, full screen.

Comment: my console doesnt show until its loadeed. Try resetting the window layout to factory

Comment: @BugFinder Thanks, that solved it